# TextView autoLink attribute makes URLs text hidden

Tags: android, url, textview

I am trying to me `String` URL links in a `TextView` clickable

in xml, I am using these attributes:

```
android:autoLink="web"
android:linksClickable="true"
```

But the String URLs is hidden in the Textview, however it is clickable and can open the url normally
So where is the problem I want the link to apear like this http://example.com in the textview

EDIT: the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/pic"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:maxWidth="250dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:linksClickable="true"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingEnd="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:paddingStart="4dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_and_time_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sent_indicator_iv"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_done_white_36dp"
                android:tint="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_height="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I also noticed that if the `textview` contains a normal text concatenated with a URL text, the URLs is hidden but the other text appears normally !!

Comment: could you post the xml of the full `TextView` or the enclosing layout?  `android:autoLink="web"` will work as expected, the visibility of the string sounds like the issue.

Comment: It is visible and colored, the non-URLs strings appears fine, check the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding this attribute `android:textColorLink` solved My problem